# Installing Gazebo development files for 2.2.3 version

Tags: gazebo-2.2, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!

Novice here.

I am trying to develop a plugin for a gazebo model. It requires development files for gazebo to be installed. I am unable to install development files from this command

sudo apt-get install libgazebo2-dev

It says "Unable to locate package libgazebo2-dev"

I request help regarding this.

Gazebo version: 2.2.3,
ROS Indigo 1.11.20,
Ubuntu trusty 14.04.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15059/installing-gazebo-development-files-for-2.2.3-version/) by [srinidhisbharadwaj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2978/srinidhisbharadwaj/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 2 is deprecated, and we recommend that you use gazebo7 which is compatible with ros indigo.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros

The reason you see "Unable to locate package libgazebo2-dev" is because we did not release gazebo2 into ubuntu trusty.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2